# openlayers turn off bird´s view

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I´m using Openlayers and layer Google Satellite and I´m trying to turn off the bird´s view. I found this advice:

> It looks like you will have to poke at the underlying GMap object
>   directly - something like this should do it I think:
>   layer.mapObject.setTilt(0) The weird thing is that my reading of the
>   Google docs says that you have to explicitly turn it on if you want
>   it, and OpenLayers isn't doing that, but still seems to get it.

The problem is that I´ve just started with Openlayers and javaScript. Could someone please show me this directly in the code? Mine is:

```
var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Google Satellite",
    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22});
    map.addLayer(gsat);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, this seems to be working: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwwSB/) it boils down to line of `ghyb.mapObject.setTilt(0);`